# Orient a JXTreeTable from bottom to top

Tags: java, swing, orientation, swingx, jxtreetable

is there any way to orient a `JXTreeTable` from bottom to top? By this I mean that instead of the default layout like so:

```
Node 0
  |-     Node 0/Column 0      Node 0/Column 1
Node 1
  |-     Node 1/Column 0      Node 1/Column 1
```

I want the expanded rows to appear above the corresponding nodes, like so:

```
  |-     Node 0/Column 0      Node 0/Column 1
Node 0
  |-     Node 1/Column 0      Node 1/Column 1
Node 1
```

Comment: Node is the root all the sub-nodes inside it appear after clicking it. But in your case it is reverse. Can you explain why and what is the requirement?

Comment: no, that's not supported

Comment: @Che: I still want the sub-nodes to appear *after* clicking/opening the node, not before. I just want them to appear above the root instead of below it. What I want is a table of numerical data, split into groups of rows, with a sub-total row below each group. It should be possible to collapse each group, leaving only the sub-total displayed (similar to the sub-totals/grouping functions in Excel). If I need to have the sub-totals above each group instead of below, that's probably acceptable.

Comment: _I just want them to appear above the root instead of below it._ You have to write you custom _JXTree_ but still I think that be difficult.